# How to change chrome browsers "download pdf instead of opening" from my web application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My web application opens a pdf file in a popup or a new tab. Now, when the user has enabled the **"Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome"** under *Settings > Advanced >Site Settings*, chrome ends up downloading the pdf instead of opening this. How to prevent chrome from downloading the pdf and open it instead. Is there any API that can be called from my web application?

Comment: If displaying the pdf in an iframe doesn't work either I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: The browser feature seems pretty self explanatory; if there was some kind of api for this, users of the browser would argue that the feature is broken :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of is to use something like PDF.js, to display the PDF in the browser using javascript.

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

The Online Demo section demonstrates the idea.  Included as iframe in a snippet below.

```css
iframe
    {
        width:610px;

    }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/web/viewer.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions using Javascipt.
But later i knew PDF download thing is bound to browser settings.
Without code when i figured out problem i referred following link :
https://www.howtogeek.com/721441/how-to-download-pdfs-instead-of-previewing-them-in-chrome-firefox-and-edge/ .

And my code was like below

Javascript

```
/* Helper function */
function download_file(fileURL, fileName) {
    // for non-IE
    if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        var filename = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        save.download = fileName || filename;
           if ( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(ipad|iphone|safari)/) && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
                document.location = save.href; 
// window event not working here
            }else{
                var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
                    'view': window,
                    'bubbles': true,
                    'cancelable': false
                });
                save.dispatchEvent(evt);
                (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
            }   
    }

    // for IE < 11
    else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
        var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
        _window.document.close();
        _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
        _window.close();
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<button onClick="download_file('original_link.pdf','any_name.pdf')">Click</button>
```